# politically correct term for "poor man's ___"

Tags: phrase-requests

I used the term "poor man's ____" to talk about a less expensive but less useful alternative. One of my colleagues called me out that some people might find it offensive. Is there another term I could use instead?

Comment: *more economical*

Comment: If I could upvote you again for being cool enough to not only search for, but announce the duplicate of your question, I would.

Comment: **Budget-friendly** alternative

Comment: Budget-friendly, economical, all are good, politically correct terms. You could even just say 'a cheaper X'.

Comment: Tell this colleague that you're offended that he would consider poverty in itself offensive.  Then start hanging out with better colleagues.

Comment: Budget-friendly and economical lose the negative connotation (less useful) that I want to maintain.

Answer (score -1):

You might like **[chintzy](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/chintzy)**:

> Did you try out ProductVal? I hear it's basically a chintzy ProductPlus.

Source: Merriam Webster

Comment: Please quote the relevant definition here and then cite the source.

Comment: [Chintzy](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/chintzy) has a rather different meaning in BrE: "Of, like, or decorated with [chintz](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/chintz#chintz__2): 'a pretty, chintzy fabric'".  Consequently I didn't initially understand this suggestion at all!

Comment: The connotation of the word "chintz" has changed over time. I've just been reading Stephen Yafa's "Cotton: The Biography of a Revolutionary Fiber" and it originally referred to a type of fabric from India with hand-painted designs, which became fashionable in Europe in the 1600s. Not sure when it became synonymous for gaudy or low-quality. (edit: [this source](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=chintz) says one of George Eliot's works in 1851.)